# postgresql ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT for 2 constraints

Tags: postgresql, sql-insert, upsert

In am currently working with PostgreSQL 9.5 and was wondering if the is a possibility to include names of 2 constraints in the ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT statement. My sql is below

```
INSERT INTO LIVE.TABLE (column1, column2, column3)
SELECT DISTINCT ON (cloumn1) column1, column2, column3
FROM STAGE.TABLE
​ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT live.table.pkey DO NOTHING
```

This works fine however what i am trying to do is to include second constraint in ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT statement. I have tried below option but it does not seem to work for me.

```
INSERT INTO LIVE.TABLE (column1, column2, column3)
SELECT DISTINCT ON (cloumn1) column1, column2, column3
FROM STAGE.TABLE
​ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT live.table.pkey, live.table.fkey1 DO NOTHING
```

Any suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35888012/use-multiple-conflict-target-in-on-conflict-clause

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use multiple conflict\_target in ON CONFLICT clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35888012/use-multiple-conflict-target-in-on-conflict-clause)

Answer (score 6):

Seems you cannot attach two constraint name like

```
ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT live.table.pkey, live.table.fkey1 DO NOTHING
```

But you can

- `ON CONFLICT ( col1, col2 ) DO NOTHING.`

or

- `ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING`.

> Specifies which conflicts ON CONFLICT takes the alternative action on
> by choosing arbiter indexes. Either performs unique index inference,
> or names a constraint explicitly. For ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING, it is
> optional to specify a conflict_target; **when omitted, conflicts with**
> **all usable constraints (and unique indexes) are handled**. For ON
> CONFLICT DO UPDATE, a conflict_target must be provided.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT

Answer (score -4):

Create a constraint using the above columns like,

```
CONSTRAINT live_table_ukey UNIQUE(live.table.pkey, live.table.fkey1)
```

then use this key in on conflict on constraint statement.

Comment: This may be appropriate for OP (not enough information), but that's not identical to having two unique constraints, one on `pkey` and the other on `fkey1`.