# Use multiple conflict_target in ON CONFLICT clause

Tags: sql, postgresql, upsert

I have two separately unique columns in a table: `col1`, `col2`. Both have a unique index (`col1` is unique and so is `col2`).

I need `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT ... DO UPDATE` syntax, and update other columns in case of a conflict, but I can't use both columns as `conflict_target`.

It works:

```
INSERT INTO table
...
ON CONFLICT ( col1 ) 
DO UPDATE 
SET 
-- update needed columns here
```

But how to do this for several columns, something like this:

```
...
ON CONFLICT ( col1, col2 )
DO UPDATE 
SET 
....
```

Currently using Postgres 9.5.

Comment: "col1, col2, they both are unique indexed." does that mean col1 is unique and col2 is unique or are combinations of col1,col2 unique?

Comment: does that mean col1 is unique and col2 is unique, individually

Answer (score 83, accepted):

### A sample table and data

```
CREATE TABLE dupes(col1 int primary key, col2 int, col3 text,
   CONSTRAINT col2_unique UNIQUE (col2)
);

INSERT INTO dupes values(1,1,'a'),(2,2,'b');
```

### Reproducing the problem

```
INSERT INTO dupes values(3,2,'c')
ON CONFLICT (col1) DO UPDATE SET col3 = 'c', col2 = 2
```

Let's call this Q1. The result is

```
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "col2_unique"
DETAIL:  Key (col2)=(2) already exists.
```

### What the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT) says

> conflict_target can perform unique index inference. When performing
>   inference, it consists of one or more index_column_name columns and/or
>   index_expression expressions, and an optional index_predicate. All
>   table_name unique indexes that, without regard to order, contain
>   exactly the conflict_target-specified columns/expressions are inferred
>   (chosen) as arbiter indexes. If an index_predicate is specified, it
>   must, as a further requirement for inference, satisfy arbiter indexes.

This gives the impression that the following query should work, but it does not because it would actually require a together unique index on col1 and col2. However such an index would not guarantee that col1 and col2 would be unique individually which is one of the OP's requirements.

```
INSERT INTO dupes values(3,2,'c') 
ON CONFLICT (col1,col2) DO UPDATE SET col3 = 'c', col2 = 2
```

Let's call this query Q2 (this fails with a syntax error)

### Why?

Postgresql behaves this way is because what should happen when a conflict occurs on the second column is not well defined. There are number of possibilities. For example in the above Q1 query, should postgresql update `col1` when there is a conflict on `col2`? But what if that leads to another conflict on `col1`? how is postgresql expected to handle that?

### A solution

A solution is to combine ON CONFLICT with [old fashioned UPSERT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-ERROR-TRAPPING).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION merge_db(key1 INT, key2 INT, data TEXT) RETURNS VOID AS
$$
BEGIN
    LOOP
        -- first try to update the key
        UPDATE dupes SET col3 = data WHERE col1 = key1 and col2 = key2;
        IF found THEN
            RETURN;
        END IF;

        -- not there, so try to insert the key
        -- if someone else inserts the same key concurrently, or key2
        -- already exists in col2,
        -- we could get a unique-key failure
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO dupes VALUES (key1, key2, data) ON CONFLICT (col1) DO UPDATE SET col3 = data;
            RETURN;
        EXCEPTION WHEN unique_violation THEN
            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO dupes VALUES (key1, key2, data) ON CONFLICT (col2) DO UPDATE SET col3 = data;
                RETURN;
            EXCEPTION WHEN unique_violation THEN
                -- Do nothing, and loop to try the UPDATE again.
            END;
        END;
    END LOOP;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

You would need to modify the logic of this stored function so that it updates the columns exactly the way you want it to. Invoke it like

```
SELECT merge_db(3,2,'c');
SELECT merge_db(1,2,'d');
```

Comment: This is way works but a bit more work/logic than is necessary, all you have to do really is create a unique constraint on the two columns.  See my answer below.

Comment: can I use merge_db solution also if I am inserting multiple sets of VALUES at once?

Comment: @daniyel you will have to rewrite the stored function

Comment: It is unclear to me how it's useful to suggest using the old-fashioned upsert - this question is well referenced for "postgres upsert 9.5" and it could be better by explaining how to use it with all constraint_names options.

Comment: @Pak It is unclear to you because you have not read the question clearly. The op is not looking for a composite key on those fields. The other answer works for composite keys

Comment: Thanks for answering the question as written.

Answer (score 125):

`ON CONFLICT` requires a unique index* to do the conflict detection. So you just need to create a unique index on both columns:

```
t=# create table t (id integer, a text, b text);
CREATE TABLE
t=# create unique index idx_t_id_a on t (id, a);
CREATE INDEX
t=# insert into t values (1, 'a', 'foo');
INSERT 0 1
t=# insert into t values (1, 'a', 'bar') on conflict (id, a) do update set b = 'bar';
INSERT 0 1
t=# select * from t;
 id | a |  b  
----+---+-----
  1 | a | bar
```

* In addition to unique indexes, you can also use [exclusion constraints](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-EXCLUSION). These are a bit more general than unique constraints. Suppose your table had columns for `id` and `valid_time` (and `valid_time` is a `tsrange`), and you wanted to allow duplicate `id`s, but not for overlapping time periods. A unique constraint won't help you, but with an exclusion constraint you can say "exclude new records if their `id` equals an old `id` and also their `valid_time` overlaps its `valid_time`."

Comment: What this creates is a together unique index  create unique index idx_t_id_a on t (id, a); Of course the OP doesn't state clearly whether the two columns are unique individually or together.

Comment: Why postgres sometimes says there is no column named after the index and fails to use `ON CONFLICT` ?

Comment: @Pak it sounds like you should write your own question with the specific command you're using and the error message you receive.

Comment: @PaulAJungwirth I don't know, your answer is spot on - a unique index as a constraint for the `on conflict` command. The error is just "column my_index_name does not exist".

Comment: I did try this anyway with a separate unique constraint on each column as the OP was asking, and it didn't work. Not that I expected it to, but I was hoping.

Comment: _"I have two columns in table col1, col2, they both are unique indexed (col1 is unique and so is col2)."_ - this answer is no longer valid since op edited their question.

Comment: but it does not work when you don't have permission to modify the schema, you just can read and insert and the table has pk and unique

Comment: @Paul A Jungwirth.  Good hint with exclusion constraint. The answer is technically incorrect though. OP asked for both field being uniq on their own.  What we need is some exclusion constraint for `(id == old_id || a == old_a )`

Comment: -1: doesn't answer the question and `ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE not supported with exclusion constraints` is the error you'll get if you try to use an exclusion constraint here.

Comment: The OP clearly states that both columns are independently unique: col1 is unique and so is col2. Your answer provides no solution for this.

Answer (score 10):

In nowadays is (seems) impossible. Neither the last version of the `ON CONFLICT`  [syntax](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-insert.html) permits to repeat the clause, nor with [CTE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/queries-with.html) is possible: not is possible to breack the INSERT from ON CONFLICT to add more conflict-targets.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using postgres 9.5 or later, you can use the EXCLUDED space.

Example taken from [What's new in PostgreSQL 9.5](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/What%27s_new_in_PostgreSQL_9.5#INSERT_..._ON_CONFLICT_DO_NOTHING.2FUPDATE_.28.22UPSERT.22.29):

```
INSERT INTO user_logins (username, logins)
VALUES ('Naomi',1),('James',1)
ON CONFLICT (username)
DO UPDATE SET logins = user_logins.logins + EXCLUDED.logins;
```

Comment: Works like a charm on postgres 9.5+ too

Comment: This missed the point of the question.

Answer (score 2):

```
ON CONFLICT ( col1, col2 )
DO UPDATE 
SET
```

works fine. but you **should not update** `col1`, `col2` in the `SET` section.

Comment: Misses the point of the question.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be the case that for the OP `col1` and `col2` are independently unique. So that a combined unique constrained will NOT solve the insert/on conflict problem, as suggested in other answers.

One solution to this is a CTE which firstly only inserts a new row with `col1` set and assigns a random value for `col2` (avoiding a constraint violation on `col2`). And only then it updates `col2` to its final value. Now this is what happens:

1. If `col1` is duplicated, the first clause's conflict will hit and not insert a new row. Otherwise a new row is inserted with `col1` set to its final value and `col2` set to a temporary and unique value.
2. If `col2` is duplicated, the second clause's conflict will hit and simply store the final value of `:col2`. Either for the existing row or for the newly created row from the insert clause.

Given that `col1` and `col2` are both strings/texts, we can use `gen_random_uuid()::text` to generate a unique string for the first insert clause:

```
with
    row as (
        insert into table(col1, col2)
        values(:col1, gen_random_uuid()::text)
        on conflict(col1) do set col1 = :col1
        returning col1
    )
update table
set col2 = :col2
from row
where row.col1 = :col1
returning col1, col2
```

with `:col1` and `:col2` being variables passed to the query.

Now if your column isn't a string/text you can come up with other unique values such as temporarily assigning `-1` to `col2`, knowing that all your values are otherwise positive.

For when you have more than 2 independently unique columns, above approach scales in so far as you can move more (and even all) column updates into the CTE clause:

```
with
    row as (
        insert into table(col1, col2, ..., colN)
        values(
            :col1,
            gen_random_uuid()::text,
            ...
            gen_random_uuid()::text,
        )
        on conflict(col1) do set col1 = :col1
        returning col1
    ),
    col2_update as (
        update table
        set col2 = :col2
        from row
        where row.col1 = :col1
    ),
    ...
    colN_update as (
        update table
        set colN = :colN
        from row
        where row.col1 = :col1
    )
select col1, col2, ..., colN from row
```

Comment: While it is certainly a solution and it is helpful, this feels like a workaround. Why would we want to insert random values in our query just to avoid postgres from throwing ? There must be a way here...

Answer (score 1):

#### Clean solution

This achieves what the question asks for:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_upsert_double(_uniq1 int, _uniq2 int, _val text)
  RETURNS void 
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   LOOP
      -- covers **all** unique violations
      INSERT INTO double_uniq
             ( uniq1,  uniq2,  val) 
      VALUES (_uniq1, _uniq2, _val) 
      ON     CONFLICT DO NOTHING;

      EXIT WHEN FOUND;

      -- updating *two* rows is a corner case possibility!
      -- take care to cover **all** possible unique violations
      UPDATE double_uniq
      SET    val = _val
      WHERE  uniq1 = _uniq1
      OR     uniq2 = _uniq2;

      EXIT WHEN FOUND;
   END LOOP;
END
$func$;
```

Call:

```
SELECT f_upsert_double(1, 2, 'foo');
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/yeylt-A-)

Can easily be adapted to return a resulting ID or whatever.

Works for **single-row** UPSERT.

It handles **all race conditions** that could develop with concurrent writes around the two `UNIQUE` constraints gracefully. The loop guarantees that either `INSERT` or `UPDATE` succeeds eventually. In reality, the function will hardly ever loop at all.
Here is a discussion and a step-by-step explanation why the loop is necessary:

- [Race conditions between INSERT ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING and SELECT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69052005/race-conditions-between-insert-on-conflict-do-nothing-and-select)

Never raises an exception for either `UNIQUE` constraint, so no need for an `EXCEPTION` clause. That's important because an `EXCEPTION` clause in a PL/pgSQL code block butchers performance and results in problems like this one:

- [How to improve bulk inserts to Postgres DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77517600/how-to-improve-bulk-inserts-to-postgres-db/77519317)

So it's also **as cheap as it gets**.

Note: address **all** possible unique violations in the `UPDATE` (from all `PRIMARY KEY`, `UNIQUE` and `EXCLUDE` constraints), or you can get an endless loop!

Related:

- [Is SELECT or INSERT in a function prone to race conditions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15939902/is-select-or-insert-in-a-function-prone-to-race-conditions/15950324#15950324)

#### Dirty problem

That said, in most cases you should not have to do this to begin with. It's a questionable DB design and workflow.
Typically, the situation arises when only one of `(col1, col2)` can have a value, while the other one must be `null`. Then there is a clean solution with **two mutually exclusive partial unique indexes**.

Or, better yet, merge the two `UNIQUE` constraints into one using the `NULLS NOT DISTINCT` in **Postgres 15** or later. See:

- [UPSERT based on UNIQUE constraint with NULL values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69746862/upsert-based-on-unique-constraint-with-null-values/69747756#69747756)

Related:

- [Error "no unique or exclusion constraint matching ON CONFLICT" for composite keys with overlapping columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77539545/error-no-unique-or-exclusion-constraint-matching-on-conflict-for-composite-key/77540178#77540178)

Answer (score 0):

Vlad got the right idea.

First you have to create a table unique constraint on the columns `col1, col2`  Then once you do that you can do the following:

```
INSERT INTO dupes values(3,2,'c') 
ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT dupes_pkey 
DO UPDATE SET col3 = 'c', col2 = 2
```

Comment: Sorry but you have misunderstand the question. The OP doesn't want a together unique constraint.

Answer (score 0):

You can typically (I would think) generate a statement with only one `on conflict` that  specifies the one and only constraint that is of relevance, for the thing you are inserting.

Because typically, only one constraint is the "relevant" one, at a time. (If many, then I'm wondering if something is weird / oddly-designed, hmm.)

Example:
<sub>(License: *Not* CC0, only CC-By)</sub>

```
// there're these unique constraints:
//   unique (site_id, people_id, page_id)
//   unique (site_id, people_id, pages_in_whole_site)
//   unique (site_id, people_id, pages_in_category_id)
// and only *one* of page-id, category-id, whole-site-true/false
// can be specified. So only one constraint is "active", at a time.

val thingColumnName = thingColumnName(notfificationPreference)

val insertStatement = s"""
  insert into page_notf_prefs (
    site_id,
    people_id,
    notf_level,
    page_id,
    pages_in_whole_site,
    pages_in_category_id)
  values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
  -- There can be only one on-conflict clause.
  on conflict (site_id, people_id, $thingColumnName)   <—— look
  do update set
    notf_level = excluded.notf_level
  """

val values = List(
  siteId.asAnyRef,
  notfPref.peopleId.asAnyRef,
  notfPref.notfLevel.toInt.asAnyRef,
  // Only one of these is non-null:
  notfPref.pageId.orNullVarchar,
  if (notfPref.wholeSite) true.asAnyRef else NullBoolean,
  notfPref.pagesInCategoryId.orNullInt)

runUpdateSingleRow(insertStatement, values)
```

And:

```
private def thingColumnName(notfPref: PageNotfPref): String =
  if (notfPref.pageId.isDefined)
    "page_id"
  else if (notfPref.pagesInCategoryId.isDefined)
    "pages_in_category_id"
  else if (notfPref.wholeSite)
    "pages_in_whole_site"
  else
    die("TyE2ABK057")
```

The `on conflict` clause is dynamically generated, depending on what I'm trying to do. If I'm inserting a notification preference, for a page — then there can be a unique conflict, on the `site_id, people_id, page_id` constraint. And if I'm configuring notification prefs, for a category — then instead I know that the constraint that can get violated, is `site_id, people_id, category_id`.

So I can, and fairly likely you too, in your case?, generate the correct `on conflict (... columns )`, because I know what I *want* to do, and then I know which single one of the many unique constraints, is the one that can get violated.

Answer (score -1):

1. Create a constraint (foreign index, for example).

OR/AND

2. Look at existing constraints (\d  in psq).
3. Use ON CONSTRAINT(constraint_name) in the INSERT clause.

Answer (score -1):

Kind of hacky but I solved this by concatenating the two values from col1 and col2 into a new column, col3 (kind of like an index of the two) and compared against that. This only works if you need it to match BOTH col1 and col2.

```
INSERT INTO table
...
ON CONFLICT ( col3 ) 
DO UPDATE 
SET 
-- update needed columns here
```

Where col3 = the concatenation of the values from col1 and col2.

Comment: you can create a unique index for those two columns and give that constraint in `on conflict`.

Comment: @KishoreRelangi What if they do not have a unique index rather a normal index?

Answer (score -1):

I get I am late to the party but for the people looking for answers I found this:
[here](https://www.dbrnd.com/2017/04/postgresql-9-5-multiple-columns-or-keys-in-on-conflict-clause/)

```py
INSERT INTO tbl_Employee 
VALUES (6,'Noor')
ON CONFLICT (EmpID,EmpName)
DO NOTHING;
```

Comment: Ben, this is unfortunately wrong because you have omitted that the user needs to add a constraint on the EmpId and EmpNAme columns.

Answer (score -8):

ON CONFLICT is very clumsy solution, run

```
UPDATE dupes SET key1=$1, key2=$2 where key3=$3    
if rowcount > 0    
  INSERT dupes (key1, key2, key3) values ($1,$2,$3);
```

works on Oracle, Postgres and all other database

Comment: It's not atomic, so it could fail and produce wrong results in case of multiple connections at the same time.

Comment: Didn't you mean `rowcount <= 0`? (i.e. do the insert if the update failed)