# How to do same thing on multiple conflicts in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

For example if I have a table:

```
create table test(

    username                varchar(50)   PRIMARY KEY,      
    customer                varchar(12),
    nickname                varchar(12)  
);

create unique index unique_customer_nickname on test(customer,nickname);
```

Therefore username is unique and (customer,nickname) together are unique.

Then If I want to write an upsert statement like this:

```
Insert into test(username,customer,nickname) values('utest','ctest','ntest') 
on conflict(username) or on conflict(customer,nickname) DO UPDATE ....
```

but this gives me syntax error.
I also tried `on (conflict(username) or conflict(customer,nickname))` 
but this also returns a syntax error.

so what I want is for different conflicts to perform the same thing.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35888012/use-multiple-conflict-target-in-on-conflict-clause please read this