# POSTGRES - Handling several ON CONFLICT constraints/indexes

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

Have the following in the table where:

```
CONSTRAINT unique_position UNIQUE (id,city,type)
```

and

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX unique_position_sat_null ON public."position" (id,city) where type is null
```

**on insert conflict** there is currently:

```
ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT unique_position DO UPDATE SET
        .....
```

How can I incorporate both unique_position and unique_position_sat_null into **ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT**

Tried:

```
ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT unique_position DO UPDATE SET
            .....,
ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT unique_position_sat_null DO UPDATE SET
            .....,
```

and

```
ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT unique_position and unique_position_sat_null  DO UPDATE SET
            .....,
```

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use multiple conflict\_target in ON CONFLICT clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35888012/use-multiple-conflict-target-in-on-conflict-clause)

Comment: Agreed that it's a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, unique indexes and unique constraints are not the same things in Postgres.

When you define a unique index, not constraint, Postgres doesn't create a constraint with the same name (in case of collisions during INSERTs it will produce error "unique constraint violation" mentioning index' name, but this is a minor bug, see https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/CAH2-Wzn-uXcLgC5uFbqe2rUfmJWP9AxKnMKAEgqU26hbURxk5A%40mail.gmail.com#CAH2-Wzn-uXcLgC5uFbqe2rUfmJWP9AxKnMKAEgqU26hbURxk5A@mail.gmail.com)

So you cannot use index name like it is a constraint name.

You could do ALTER TABLE .. ADD CONSTRAINT .. UNIQUE, but it cannot be unique.

So this can be considered as a not yet implemented feature in Postgres -- either "ON CONFLICT" clause needs to learn how to use index names or ALTER TABLE .. ADD CONSTRAINT .. UNIQUE needs to be patched to allow partial constraints.

I suggest discussing it in pgsql-hackers@ mailing list (e.g. if you answer thread mentioned above, explaining your problem, it would be awesome).