# iBatis/Java - on conflict on index

Tags: java, sql, apache, postgresql, ibatis

In table:

```
CONSTRAINT unique_position UNIQUE (id,city,type)
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX unique_position_sat_null ON public."position" (id,city) where type is null
```

When we insert into a table with iBatis we'd like to use:

```
ON CONFLICT ON INDEX unique_position DO UPDATE SET
        .....
```

As I understand we cannot use index in `ON CONFLICT` in POSTGRES.

Are there any other options to handle this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is duplicated question. I answered in your previous one [POSTGRES - Handling several ON CONFLICT constraints/indexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44728007/postgres-handling-several-on-conflict-constraints-indexes)

In short: no, there is currently no way to mention a partial index name in ON CONFLICT clause.

A workaround in your case would be (probably, depending on your logic): stop using NULLs in "type" column at all, use "-1" instead and work with 3-column unique constraint.

Comment: Thanks, will try to go with -1 instead.