# UPSERT using ID only when provioded in PostgreSQL

Tags: python, postgresql, sql-update, sql-insert, upsert

With the following `PostgreSQL` query, I would like to "upsert" a row such that if the row data I provide contains data for the field "id", it will be used, and if if not, it will be autogenerated by postgres. Is this possible to carry out?

**Schema**

```
create table if not exists spotify_crons (
      id uuid default uuid_generate_v4 () primary key
    , name varchar(32) unique
    , seed_artists varchar(32)
    , seed_tracks varchar(32)
    , seed_genres varchar(256)
    , created_at timestamptz not null default now()
    , updated_at timestamptz not null default now()
);
comment on column spotify_crons.id is 'The UUID of the cron entry';
comment on column spotify_crons.name is 'The unique name of the cron entry';
comment on column spotify_crons.seed_artists is 'The spotify artist seed of the cron entry';
comment on column spotify_crons.seed_tracks is 'The spotify track seed of the cron entry';
comment on column spotify_crons.seed_genres is 'The spotify genre seed of the cron entry';
comment on column spotify_crons.created_at is 'The time of creation for the cron entry';
comment on column spotify_crons.updated_at is 'The time of last update for the cron entry';
```

**Query**

```
insert into spotify_crons
    (
          id
        , name
        , seed_artists
        , seed_tracks
        , seed_genres
        , created_at
        , updated_at
    )
values
    (
          case
            when %(id)s is distinct from null
            then %(id)s
            else gen_random_uuid()
          end
        , %(name)s
        , %(seed_artists)s
        , %(seed_tracks)s
        , %(seed_genres)s
        , now()
        , now()
    )
on
    conflict (id)
do
    update
set
    name = %(name)s
  , seed_artists = %(seed_artists)s
  , seed_tracks = %(seed_tracks)s
  , seed_genres = %(seed_genres)s
  , updated_at = now()
returning id
;
```

Examples:

```
# Should insert new row with auto generated ID
{ "id": None, "name": "Hello", ...}

# Should insert the row with the provided UUID
{ "id": "some_uuid_that_doesn't exist", "name": "Hello", ...}

# Should update the row with the matching UUID with new data
{ "id": "some_uuid_that_exists", "name": "Hello", ...}
```

PS: I am using `Python 3.7` with `psycopg 3` if that matters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```sql
INSERT INTO spotify_crons (id, name,
                          -- ...
                          )
VALUES (COALESCE(%(id)s::UUID, uuid_generate_v4()),
        %(name)s,
        -- ...
       )
ON CONFLICT (id)
DO UPDATE SET name=EXCLUDED.name,
              -- ...
```

- Using the `DEFAULT` keyword in the `COALESCE` expression like this wouldn't work, but it shouldn't really be an issue if you know you want to generate a v4 random UUID anyway: `COALESCE(%(id)s::UUID, DEFAULT)`.
- You may also run into other problems if you get conflicts with the unique name constraint, in which case [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38066008/372643) may be of interest.