# Enforce 2 unique constraints on upserts in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, constraints, upsert

I have a table where I save contacts data

```sql
                                                Table "public.person"
            Column             |           Type           | Collation | Nullable |              Default               
-------------------------------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+------------------------------------
 id                            | integer                  |           | not null | nextval('person_id_seq'::regclass)
 full_name                     | character varying        |           |          | 
 role                          | character varying        |           |          | 
 first_name                    | character varying        |           |          | 
 last_name                     | character varying        |           |          | 
 linkedin_slug                 | character varying        |           |          | 
 email                         | character varying        |           |          | 
 domain                        | character varying        |           |          | 
 created_at                    | timestamp with time zone |           |          | now()
 updated_at                    | timestamp with time zone |           |          | now()
Indexes:
    "pk_person" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "ix_person_domain" btree (domain)
    "ix_person_email" btree (email)
    "ix_person_updated_at" btree (updated_at)
    "uq_person_full_name_domain" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (full_name, domain)
```

I add data to this table from several sources. Some sources have Linkedin profiles data about people, other sources have email data. Sometimes the full names are not equal, even if they refer to the same person.

And I want to do upserts to not have duplicated data. For now I'm using the constraint on `full_name, domain`. I know it's an oversimplification as there may be 2 different people with the same full name in the same company, but that's not a problem at this moment.

The problem comes when a person has different full names in the different data sources I use, but the same Linkedin profile, so I know it's the same person.

Or when they're associated to 2 domains from the same company.

In those cases, I end up with duplicated rows for some people. For example:

| full_name | domain | linkedin_slug |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Raffi SARKISSIAN | getlago.com | sarkissianraffi |
| Raffi Sarkissian | getlago.com | sarkissianraffi |

That one is a trivial one that could be solved making the constraint on `lower(full_name), domain`, but there are cases where the last name is not the same (people have more than 1 last name in many countries and they may not use them all sometimes).

Another example

| full_name | domain | linkedin_slug |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Amir Manji | tenjin.com | amirmanji |
| Amir Manji | tenjin.io | amirmanji |

Ideally I'd like to be able to enforce more than 1 constraint at the same time in Postgres, but I've seen [it's not easy or out-of-the-box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35888012/use-multiple-conflict-target-in-on-conflict-clause). I don't/can't create a unique constraint on `(full_name, domain, linkedin_slug)`. And the solution from the accepted answer is not so good for my use case because I have way more cols than in that example and I'd have to write a different upsert function for each data source (not all of them have the same attributes)

What I'm thinking is making a script to deduplicate the info 'manually' after inserting new data, but I'm not sure if there are better ways to address this.

How would you go about it?

Comment: That's not what the link says at all. It's not even about creating multiple constraints, it's about the `ON CONFLICT` clause. You can create as many UNIQUE constraints as you want. It's the same as creating multiple unique indexes. In fact, unique constraints are backed by a unique index to speed up the uniqueness check

Comment: Unless by "more than one" you mean "either one but not both".

Comment: Yes, I can't create a unique index on the 3 columns because sometimes for a given `linkedin_slug`, `domain` would be the same but `full_name` would be different.

Comment: That's a *single* multi-column constraint, not multiple constraints. You may be able to do this if you can come up with a function that generates the same value in every case and create a unique constraint over it. On the other hand, it's typically a lot easier to clean data in code when loading it than try to clean it after the fact

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos do you have some examples of that? I'd have to write a function that returns the same value for all these sets of (name, slug, domain): (name_a, slug_a, domain_a), (name_b, slug_a, domain_a), (name_a, NULL, domain_a), (NULL, slug_a, domain_a), (name_a, slug_a, domain_b)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: I ended up doing it by first doing upserts enforcing `full_name, domain` is unique, then deduplicating on `linkedin_slug` running a script that basically groups by `linkedin_slug` and gets whatever values are not null:

```sql
    SELECT
        max(id) id
        , max(full_name) full_name
        , max("role") "role"
        , max(first_name) first_name
        , max(last_name) last_name
        , linkedin_slug
        , max(linkedin_id) linkedin_id
        , max(email) email
        , max("domain") "domain"
        , max(yc_bio) yc_bio
        , min(created_at) created_at
        , now() updated_at
        , max(extrapolated_email_confidence) extrapolated_email_confidence
        , max(email_status) email_status
        , max(email_searched_on_apollo::text)::bool email_searched_on_apollo
    FROM person
    GROUP BY linkedin_slug
    HAVING count(*) > 1
```

And then updating the original table with data from this subquery.

The full gist is [here](https://gist.github.com/xoelop/ff42ab06406e180b71a92d7753988793)

Answer (score 0):

We cannot create unique constraints on functions of columns but we can create unique constraints on virtual columns which are functions of columns, for example `LOWER()`. For domain I have created a virtual column with the part before the first point. This is then subject to a unique constraint.
NB: Virtual columns are supported in Postgres 12 or higher.
By these means we detect

- that 'Joe BLOGGS' is a duplicate of `Joe Bloggs`
- that `hello.UK` duplicate `hello.com`
- that `invalid`is not an e-mail address.
  Checking that an e-mail adresses is valid is complicated. A simple check that there is an `@` followed by a point avoids telephone numbers etc.
  You will have to determine which CONSTRAINTS are enforcable and which may stop you entering data which should be acceptable.

> ```
> create table person (
>  id                             serial     not null       ,
>  full_name                        varchar(25)                 ,
>  role                             varchar(25)                 ,
>  first_name                       varchar(25)                 ,
>  last_name                        varchar(25)                 ,
>  linkedin_slug                    varchar(25)                 ,
>  email                            varchar(25)                 ,
>  domain                           varchar(25)                 ,
>  created_at                        timestamp  default  now()  ,
>  updated_at                        timestamp  default  now()  ,
>  domainRoot varchar(25) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ( LEFT(domain, STRPOS(domain,'.')-1)) STORED,
>  l_fname varchar(25) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ( LOWER(full_name)) STORED,
>  CONSTRAINT "pk_person" PRIMARY KEY (id),
>  CONSTRAINT  "uq_person_full_name_domain" UNIQUE (full_name, domain),
>  CONSTRAINT  "uq_lower_full_name" UNIQUE (l_fname),
>  CONSTRAINT "uq_email" UNIQUE (email),
>  CONSTRAINT "ck_valid_email" CHECK (email LIKE '%@%.%'),
>  CONSTRAINT "uq_domain_root" UNIQUE (domainRoot)
> );
> ```

> ```
> insert into person (full_name) values ('Joe Bloggs'),('Mrs Brown')
> ```

> ```
> insert into person (full_name) values ('Joe BLOGGS')
> ```
>
> ```
> ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "uq_lower_full_name"
> ```

DETAIL:  Key (l_fname)=(joe bloggs) already exists.

> 

> ```
> update person set email = 'invalid', updated_at = now()
> ```
>
> ```
> ERROR:  new row for relation "person" violates check constraint "ck_valid_email"
> ```

DETAIL:  Failing row contains (1, Joe Bloggs, null, null, null, null, invalid, null, 2022-04-08 16:22:03.749316, 2022-04-08 16:22:03.751928, null, joe bloggs).

> 

> ```
> update person set email = 'ok@dom.com' where id = 2;
> ```

> ```
> update person set domain = 'hello.com' , updated_at = now() where id = 1;
> ```

> ```
> update person set domain = 'hello.UK' where id = 2
> ```
>
> ```
> ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "uq_domain_root"
> ```

DETAIL:  Key (domainroot)=(hello) already exists.

> 

> ```
> SELECT * FROM person
> ```
>
> ```
> id | full_name  | role | first_name | last_name | linkedin_slug | email      | domain    | created_at                 | updated_at                 | domainroot | l_fname   
> -: | :--------- | :--- | :--------- | :-------- | :------------ | :--------- | :-------- | :------------------------- | :------------------------- | :--------- | :---------
>  2 | Mrs Brown  | null | null       | null      | null          | ok@dom.com | null      | 2022-04-08 16:22:03.749316 | 2022-04-08 16:22:03.749316 | null       | mrs brown 
>  1 | Joe Bloggs | null | null       | null      | null          | null       | hello.com | 2022-04-08 16:22:03.749316 | 2022-04-08 16:22:03.753807 | hello      | joe bloggs
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=f58fd3a257fdced7381a90c6858f11e1)*