# Handle conflicts on both primary key and foreign key while inserting new rows in Postgres SQL table

Tags: postgresql

Let's just say there is a table called "plays" with the following columns:

```
play_id: primary key, varchar, uuid
event_id: foreign key, varchar
player_id: foreign key, varchar,
date: Date object
time: timestamp object
```

The values of `event_id` and `player_id` might not have existed in the targeted tables (which are `events` and `players` respectively) when inserting new rows into this table, and it's possible to insert rows with the same `play_id` multiple times.

What I tried is

```
INSERT INTO plays (play_id, event_id, player_id, date, time)
VALUES ('e092068d-edc5-4e67-99ea-b2b429eaa4f0', '12345', '54321', '2023-01-01', '08:23:34.23'),
'027d427b-ca50-4756-8513-185f1bf69665', '418590', '16263', '2023-03-12', '12:04:53.00'),
('03c67512-5529-4142-b443-f7994ed7b2bc', '418590', '16263', '2023-03-16', '10:31:31.70'),
('06885f46-b3e7-43ce-be00-a08fc9e220b6', '443484', '17057', '2023-03-28', '17:17:18.63')
ON CONFLICT (play_id) DO UPDATE SET play_od = EXCLUDED.play_id, event_id = EXCLUDED.event_id, player_id = EXCLUDED.player_id, date = EXCLUDED.date, time = EXCLUDED.time
ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT plays_event_id_fkey DO NOTHING
ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT plays_player_id_fkey DO NOTHING;
```

However, it says that there is a syntax error at or near the second "ON", which kind of indicates that we are not allowed to use multiple `ON CONFLICT` in one command at the same time. If so, is there a way to work around and how? Do I need to create a custom constraint for this scenario?

Comment: here is most of what woudl be needed to reproduce your issue https://dbfiddle.uk/csFlUfVw  - add the additional constraints - BUT first read this https://stackoverflow.com/a/38066008/2067753

Comment: I found my question is a little duplicated with this one: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/294059/214680. And it means there's no easy way to do so, so case is closed for now.