# Catch multiple constraints with ON CONFLICT upsert pgsql

Tags: postgresql, unique-constraint, upsert, unique-index

I use an INSERT ON CONFLICT UPDATE [upsert](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html) to perform regular syncs from low to high environments. I defer all constraints before the upsert, however I recently had to add a [partial unique index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-partial.html) which is not deferrable, and it's causing the job to fail.

I was using something like this to work around the anticipated primary key conflicts:

```
INSERT INTO high_side_table0 (id, col1, col2, col3, boolean1) 
SELECT (id, col1, col2, col3, boolean1)
FROM new_or_modified_records_from_low_side_table0
ON CONFLICT (id)
DO UPDATE SET col1 = EXCLUDED.col1, col2 = EXCLUDED.col2, col3 = EXCLUDED.col3, boolean1 = EXCLUDED.boolean1;
```

The partial unique index I recently added prevents a duplicate combination of three columns in cases where a particular boolean value in that record is FALSE.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX table0_col2_col3_boolean1_unique ON table0 (col2, col3, boolean1) WHERE NOT boolean1;
```

If a duplicate+FALSE combination is included in the upsert, it should fail to insert then update the existing (duplicate) row with which it conflicted. I can do this using the same upsert code above but replacing the CONFLICT target with the following: `ON CONFLICT (col2, col3, boolean1)`. Unfortunately, I can't add id to the CONFLICT set `ON CONFLICT (id, col2, col3, boolean1)` because this seems to treat each column as independent. Nor can I add id to the UNIQUE INDEX because it wouldn't properly catch the duplicates I'm looking for.

To summarize, I need to catch two separate potential constraint violation types but in a single upsert transaction. Something like this:

```
INSERT INTO high_side_table0 (id, col1, col2, col3, boolean1) 
SELECT (id, col1, col2, col3, my_boolean)
FROM new_or_modified_records_from_low_side_table0
ON CONFLICT (id) OR (col2, col3, boolean1)
DO UPDATE SET col1 = EXCLUDED.col1, col2 = EXCLUDED.col2, col3 = EXCLUDED.col3, boolean1 = EXCLUDED.boolean1;
```

After skimming through a lot of postgres documentation and stack overflow posts, I'm leaning toward creating a custom upsert function (one example shown in the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35888012/use-multiple-conflict-target-in-on-conflict-clause)). Would love if there is a built in way to accomplish this, or if anyone has any insight as to why this might be a bad idea in the first place.

Comment: `On Conflict` **cannot**  handle multiple potential constraint violation, it is 1 max. If you are running v15 of higher you can use the [Merge](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/sql-merge.html) statement which can handle multiple constraints. However, it's structure can be somewhat complicated and may take some time to figure out.